# How to pass bundle object from activity to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments. Whatever data is passed from 1st fragment to the activity, I want to pass it to the 2nd fragment. I'm using bundle object to pass data. But I have a condition where i'm checking, whether a device is a handset to tablet. 
Here's the module:
            p

```
ublic void clickItem(int position) {
            DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container2);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("pos", position);
            if (fragment == null) {
                DetailFragment detail=new DetailFragment();
                detail.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceFragment(detail);

            } else {
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                replaceNewFragment(fragment);

            }
    }
```

When i click on any item of the first fragments, control goes to clickItem method. In this method, I'm checking whether a device ia a handset or a tablet. 
This is the replaceFragment method & replaceNewFragment method:

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    private void replaceNewFragment(Fragment fragment){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container2, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

It worked on a handset. But in Tablet when i click the item, fragment is displayed in next page just like a handset. Y its happening. I have defined the xml file in layout-large. Can anyone please tell me, where I have gone wrong?

Comment: post the stack trace.

Comment: 05-09 01:57:13.306: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 01:57:13.306: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): Process: com.example.fruitsappfragmentdemo, PID: 1492
05-09 01:57:13.306: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 01:57:13.306: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
05-09 01:57:13.306: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:429)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Check first

```
DetailFragment fragment=(DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container2);
if(fragment!=null){
// Then do your operation
```

Comment: then When should i pass the bundle object?

Comment: B'coz untill n unless there is any Fragment recorder in Stack, how can you get the Object. So first add the Fragment.

Comment: after adding the fragments, I should pass bundle object?

Comment: I added the bundle object after adding the fragments. i.e. after if and else statements. Still I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The fragment instance in null then how ll you pass the bundle to that.

try this

```
 if(fragment==null){

            replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
        else{
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            replaceNewFragment(fragment);

        }
```

and in `replaceFragment(fragment);` method if u create a new Fragment the after u add the setArguments to the fragment.

Comment: It worked for handset.But in for tablet, when i click the item, it goes to next page. I have given the layout in the same page, Y its going next page?

Comment: Do i need to create new Fragment inside replaceFragment(fragment); or inside the if statement

Comment: if fragment is null u need to create a fragment instance. in your case check why fragment is null by getting from (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container2);

Comment: Its not crashing.It's working for handset.But for tablet,when i click the item, it goes to next page. I have given the layout in the same page, Y its going next page?